# virtual host doesn't work on tomcat7

Tags: dns, tomcat7, host

I have a web running on Tomcat7 (installed on ubuntu 14.10). The application is available at `localhost:8080/myapp`.

I would like to access it with the url : `myapp.com`

I've tried many tutorials on the web (update server.xml by adding a , update /etc/hosts file, etc). None of them work.
If you know how I could achieve this, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your web application as a `ROOT.war` under webapps.

Open your `server.xml` and change the port from `8080` to `80`.

Add below line to your [host file.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system)

```
127.0.0.1    myapp.com
```

Now try http://myapp.com

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! What if I have several apps deployed on my tomcat, how could that solution be possible still?

Comment: I didn't test it before saying thanks, I should have... your solution doesn't work either.:/

Comment: Check [LAN Settings](http://jzvb4w.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pFFzFU8lHkXPfYDedlBciYZHuC0Z0xGgA3zAn3SF03uR2nRVbEBcmYM2mblFZM07ZMi3nigjwu-wxa6JzDWkVnTbaBuL-z9ji/Internet%20Options.png) on your browser and make sure all options under `Automatic Configuration` and `Proxy Server`are unchecked. The method in answer works for me. I was able to access tomcat home page as http://myapp.com. Tomcat is hosted as ROOT under Webapps. Your best deal is to use [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) as a proxy to your Tomcat apps and you can do a lot with Apache. Good Luck!